# What is this frame(?) piece and/or where could I find out?

Tags: ford, part-identification, f-150, frame

1994 Ford F-150...4x4...5.8L...Automatic

This is looking straight back from just under the front bumper on the driver's side. The coiled tube on the left side of the picture is housed/inset into a member that has cracked - what is this piece called, or where could I find this out?[image]

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: It's an engine crossmember.

Comment: Not solved until you repair or replace it.